# Is there maximum size of string data type in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

Google a ton but haven't found it anywhere. Or does that mean Hive can support arbitrary large string data type as long as cluster is allowed? If so, where I can find what is the largest size of string data type that my cluster can support?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The current documentation for Hive lists `STRING` as a valid datatype, distinct from `VARCHAR` and `CHAR`  See official apache doc here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-Strings

It wasn't immediately apparent to me that `STRING` was indeed it's own type, but if you scroll down you'll see several cases where it's used distinctly from the others.

The book [**Apache Hive Essentials**](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big-data-and-business-intelligence/9781783558575/3/ch03lvl1sec21/understanding-hive-data-types) indicates the max length of a `STRING` is 2GB.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to add following remarks:Yes, there indeed exists `STRING` type and since I work with ODBC interface of Hive, and I can tell from ODBC view that `STRING` is mapped as `SQL_VARCHAR` by ODBC driver with the maximize size of 2147483647 kb (2GB) as the link you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

**By default, the columns metadata for Hive does not specify a maximum data length for STRING columns.**

**The driver has the parameter DefaultStringColumnLength, default is 255** maximum value.

A connection string with this parameter set to maximum size would look like this: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000;DefaultStringColumnLength=32767;

(https://github.com/exasol/virtual-schemas/issues/118)

"**In the “looser” world in which Hive lives**, where it may not own the data files and has to be flexible on file format, **Hive relies on the presence of delimiters to separate fields**. Also, Hadoop and Hive emphasize optimizing disk reading and writing performance, where **fixing the lengths of column values is relatively unimportant**." from

https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-hive/9781449326944/ch03.html#Collection-Data-Types