# how to know max length of sql that hive support?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I want to insert some data into hive.

under some limits I have to use `insert`. I can not use `load local data ...`

```
INSERT into (DATABASE)::(TABLE) values (a1,b1,c1,d1),(a2,b2,c2,d2) ...
```

The question is:

some field is very long string , like article content, I have use `base64` to handle special characters, now I am looking for the max length that hive-sql support.

Comment: `STRING` is 2GB Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35030936/is-there-maximum-size-of-string-data-type-in-hive

Comment: @faizulhaque I just want to know hive-sql max statement length

Comment: If MySQL is being used as MetaStore of Hive than the limit is max_allowed_packet=1048576 (1MB) and it's derby (default) than it has no limit (not sure)